# GCP: Can Pony ORM be used with Cloud Functions and Cloud SQL

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-sql, serverless, ponyorm

The Python ORM 'Pony' (ponyorm.org) looked like a big improvement on our patchy manual SQL queries. In addition, getting Pony to work on App Engine / Python 2.7 was not successful.  At the same time, we hit some bottlenecks for App Engine and manual queries in relation to Cloud SQL connection pooling.

How can we configure the Pony ORM to connect to Google Cloud SQL from a Cloud Function invocation?

ORM: Pony
DB Driver: PyMySQL

Out of the box, connecting to db is:

```
    db.bind(provider='mysql', host='', user='', passwd='', db='')
```

host=IP doesn't work.  Cloud Functions specifically prohibits this.
"Note: By default, Cloud Functions does not support connecting to the Cloud SQL instance using TCP. Your code should not try to access the instance using an IP address (such as 127.0.0.1 or 172.17.0.1) unless you have configured Serverless VPC Access."

Is there a config that will make db connection?

Answer (score 2):

Answer… 
1) For the service account for Cloud Functions, add the Cloud SQL Client role.
2) configure 'unix_socket=' with the Instance Connection Name of the Cloud SQL

```
    db.bind(provider='mysql',unix_socket='/cloudsql/my-project:us-central1:my-project-sql',...
```

Testing 'unix_socket=' was inspired by the MySQL python library docs,
but the same config flag works for PyMySQL.  That suggests that MySQL-Python will serve as well; Pony supports both drivers.